# Move cell in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to implement `insertColumn` functionality with `Apache POI`.  As far as I can tell the only way to achieve this is to `iterate` over all `rows` in the `Sheet`, and then shift each `Cell` in each `Row` over by 1 `Cell`, and then creating a new `Cell` in the row at the required column index.

However, I noticed that only the `HSSFRow` has a `moveCell()` method, and the `XSSFRow` does not - is there a reason that moveCell is only implemented for HSSF?  Is there a reason this couldn't be added to the `Sheet` `interface` and implemented for both `Sheet` types (since our code is working with the Interfaces in order to support both .xls and .xslx file types)?

Edit:

After implementing a cell by cell, row by row move, it became apparent that this wasnt going to work for formulas since the references were not updated.  I finally found an open source LGPL library that does handle this far better than POI - openxls.  After using this library for a few weeks, I would ***not*** recommend using this library.  We've hit bug after bug and have spent more time fixing and pushing bugs to our public git repo than we've spent developing app code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this kind of varied behaviour when viewing both kinds of sheets is because the way that the .xls and .xlsx files are structured are VASTLY different. So to simply say 'is it not possible to add this to the sheet inteface' well, yes, it's possible, but it's also possible that adding this additional functionality could be extremely non-trivial. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for a decent description of why they switched to .xlsx. If you REALLY want to be interesting, change the name of your whateverMyFileis.xlsx file to whateverMyFileis.zip > then unzip it, and you can see the true extent to how they broke everything up inside of the file. Whereas if you do that for .xls, it doesn't do anything.

As to the first part of your question where you asked about implementing the insertColumn functionality. The reason this is giving you trouble, is because excel sheets are, by nature, row-based, and Apache-POI does not give very much native support for columns. Almost all of the things you would want to do involving column-based logic, would have to be implemented almost in their entirety by you. So to answer your sort of question about the only way you could see to do it, I agree, I don't offhand see a better way to create a column.

Comment: Thanks. Any views on how I could move a cell in a XSSF Row (or directly insert a new cell) with the current POI release (I have a solution for HSSF) other than a : insert new cell at end, copy last-1 cell to new end cell, and repeat for all cells in row.

Comment: Hmmm, you might have the best luck parsing the whole row into a container, and then editing that container, deleting the old row, and creating the new one in the same place with the edited data from your container. If the rows are HUGE you might have to find a more elegant solution, but apache-POI is pretty well optimized, so you shouldn't see huge drops in performance for anything short of very very large excel files